# Android ProgressDialog Annoying errors

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, progressdialog

I am building an application that uses GPS to determine users current country. Now, since GPS takes a while to find the location, while it is searching i want to show a ProgressDialog.

So inside my LocationListener, I called a ProgressDialog that i declared before called

```
pd
```

And right underneath the part where it shows i created a thread to do the GPS stuff. for some reason, the ProgressDialog isn't showing :/

Here is my code:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(TipCalculatorActivity.this, "", "Looking for GPS satellites...");
        new Thread() 
        {
          public void run() 
          {
             try
               {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(TipCalculatorActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                    countryCode = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(TipCalculatorActivity.this, "Location is not available, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                if(countryCode==null){
                    Toast.makeText(TipCalculatorActivity.this, "Location is not available, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                Toast.makeText(TipCalculatorActivity.this, countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
            }
        // dismiss the progressdialog   
          pd.dismiss();
         }
        }.start();
```

What is wrong here?!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My new code:
Where i call the AsyncTask:

```
    LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //sets and displays the lat/long when a location is provided
        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lng = loc.getLongitude();

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(TipCalculatorActivity.this, lng, lat);
        task.execute();
        Toast.makeText(TipCalculatorActivity.this, "Done :D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

The AsyncTask:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{

private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private String countryCode;

public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, double longitude, double latitude) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Looking for GPS satellites...");
}

@Override
protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        countryCode = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Location is not available, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(countryCode==null){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Location is not available, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(activity, countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: is the toast showing up immediately?

Comment: Look at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I will use an AsyncTask for that :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{

                        private Activity activity;
                        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                        private long longitude;
                        private long latitute;

            public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, Long longitude, Long latitude) {
                            super();
                this.activity = activity;
                this.longitude = longitude;
                this.latitude = latitude;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
            //do your stuff here
            return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


}
```

Call it from the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(myActivity.this, lng, lat);
task.execute();
```

Comment: Can i pass data like the lat lng variables to this AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes certainly ! Modify the constuctor of the AsynTask as you need. I edited !!

Comment: And  can i send back data? like my results for example?

Comment: Yes, you can use AsynTask.get() method. See this for more infos http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Im not sure how this works, never did anything like this. can you post an example please?

Comment: I have a new error now, i didn't do the get part yet but the ProgressDialog just isn't showing. What is wrong here???

Comment: you forgot to put "progressDialog =" in " ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Looking for GPS satellites...");"

Comment: Is it ok now ? (and you can remove the Toast "Done" btw)

Comment: Fixed that, it is still not working... Maybe there is an error with the place im starting it? Because i see the little icon on my phone that means GPS is working, but the ProgressDialog isn't showing...

Comment: OK, i noticed something weird. When i put my phone near the window to get better GPS reception, i see the dialog flashing for about half a second, and then it tells me that it is finished. the dialog wont show without the GPS reception. How can i fix that?

Comment: And if you had the boolean parameter at the end of ProgressDialog.show()? Are the Toast displayed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15469/discussion-between-arielschon12-and-alexis-cartier)